# Implicit cursor indicates that it updates all rows in the table for a given identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a simple **PL/SQL procedure** that increases the salary of an employee in the EMP table of the SCOTT schema. This receives the employee number per parameter and increment. The UPDATE statement that performs the update does not filter by that identifier and when accessing the **ROWCOUNT** of the cursor indicates that all the rows in the table were updated.

If this update I do from SQL Plus. It only updates a row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INCREASE_SALARY(
    empno EMP.EMPNO%TYPE,
    incre NUMBER
)
AUTHID DEFINER
AS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    INCREMENT_MUST_BE_GREATER_THAN_ZERO EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

    IF incre = 0 THEN
        RAISE INCREMENT_MUST_BE_GREATER_THAN_ZERO;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE TO UPDATE: ' || empno);

    UPDATE EMP
        SET SAL = SAL + (SAL * incre / 100)
        WHERE EMPNO = empno;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT)||' rows affected.');

    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO TABLA_LOG VALUES(USER, SYSDATE); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO EMPLOYEE FOUND FOR THAT ID');
    END IF;

    COMMIT WORK;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN INCREMENT_MUST_BE_GREATER_THAN_ZERO THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE INCREMENT PERCENTAGE MUST BE GREATER THAN 0'); 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR : ' || SQLCODE || 'MENSAJE: ' || SQLERRM); 
END;
/
```

When executing the procedure with the **EMPNO 7900 (JAMES)**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXEC INCREASE_SALARY(7900, 20);
```

I get the following output:

```
EMPLOYEE TO UPDATE: 7900
13 rows affected.
SALARY UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY

Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.
```

Does anyone know I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

select count(1) from EMP WHERE EMPNO = 7900;

Return 1.

I'm using Oracle Enterprise 12c. The procedure compiles. The identifier error too long does not appear.

Comment: does the following return 13 ? select count(1) from EMP WHERE EMPNO = 7900

Comment: Your procedure doesn't compile. The error is: `Error(6,5): PLS-00114: identifier 'INCREMENT_MUST_BE_GREATER_THAN' too long`. It must be up to 30 characters long, acutually it is 34 characters long ==> `INCREMENT_MUST_BE_GREATER_THAN_ZERO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `empno = empno`.  These are interpreted as the column name.

You should try to give your arguments and local variables different names:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INCREASE_SALARY (
    in_empno EMP.EMPNO%TYPE,
    iin_ncre NUMBER
)
AUTHID DEFINER
AS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    INCREMENT_MUST_BE_GREATER_THAN_ZERO EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

    IF in_incre = 0 THEN
        RAISE INCREMENT_MUST_BE_GREATER_THAN_ZERO;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE TO UPDATE: ' || in_empno);

    UPDATE EMP
        SET SAL = SAL + (SAL * in_incre / 100)
        WHERE EMPNO = in_empno;
    . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize it.

Comment: Tips: If it's not possible to change parameter name, you can prefix parameter name with procedure name like : `empno = INCREASE_SALARY.empno`.